# Syntax error in react app. Only on first load

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, netlify

Im having some trouble figuring out exactly what the issue is here.

Whenever I deploy a new version of my react application, I get this error:

`SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`

However, the interesting part of the issue is it ONLY happens on the first load. If you press refresh on the browser, the issue goes away, and doesn't happen again until a new version is pushed out.

From what I can gather from other stack overflow posts:

[React firebase error after build and deploy SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50659063/react-firebase-error-after-build-and-deploy-syntaxerror-expected-expression-go)

The issue seems to lie in the index.html file, where I am loading a js script, but html is getting loaded, and the '<' character throws the error. Also, I never see this error when developing, only once built and deployed.

I am left scratching my head since the error only happens on first load.

Here is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="/color.less" >
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <title>Kirs</title>

    <script>(function(){var w=window;var ic=w.Intercom;if(typeof ic==="function"){ic('reattach_activator');ic('update',intercomSettings);}else{var d=document;var i=function(){i.c(arguments)};i.q=[];i.c=function(args){i.q.push(args)};w.Intercom=i;function l(){var s=d.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.async=true;s.src='https://widget.intercom.io/widget/w1ycmr5d';var x=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];x.parentNode.insertBefore(s,x);}if(w.attachEvent){w.attachEvent('onload',l);}else{w.addEventListener('load',l,false);}}})()</script>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=omitted&libraries=places"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I use netlify to deploy my app, if that makes any difference.

netlify.toml:

```
# Global settings applied to the whole site.
# “base” is directory to change to before starting build, and
# “publish” is the directory to publish (relative to root of your repo).
# “command” is your build command.

[build]
  base    = ""
  publish = "build"
  command = "REACT_APP_STAGE=dev npm run build"

# Production context: All deploys to the main
# repository branch will inherit these settings.
[context.production]
  command = "REACT_APP_STAGE=prod npm run build"

# Deploy Preview context: All Deploy Previews
# will inherit these settings.
[context.deploy-preview]
  command = "REACT_APP_STAGE=dev npm run build"

# Branch Deploy context: All deploys that are not in
# an active Deploy Preview will inherit these settings.
[context.branch-deploy]
  command = "REACT_APP_STAGE=dev npm run build"

# Always redirect any request to our index.html
# and return the status code 200.
[[redirects]]
    from    = "/*"
    to      = "/index.html"
    status  = 200
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I didn't read through the entire code you posted but;  Do you always get the error if you hard refresh? (CTRL + F5)

Comment: No, doing a hard reload or an empty cache and hard reload doesn't cause the error to pop up again. Neither does an incognito, window for what it's worth.

Comment: Interesting... If it doesn't happen in incognito (which is what I would assume is a First Load scenario), can you define what you mean by "first load" more specifically?  How are you ensuring this is being replicated?

Comment: I agree with you, which I why Im so confused. I have netlify set up so that it publishes a build when I commit to the master banch on my github repo. By "first load" I mean the first time anyone visits the site after netlify has built and published a new branch.

Comment: Does the error only occur on the first pageload after you have deployed to netlify?  Does it occur locally at all?

Comment: Correct, only after a netlify does a publish. Never locally.

Comment: You should try capturing the raw response when you get the error.  There may be extraneous characters printed that are not in your index.html!

Comment: It is saying the error is in `/static/js/main.89c35a6d.js`and specifically the error is on `main.89c35a6d.js:1` from my understanding, react creates a single js file. Im guessing this is that file? Is there a way I can access that file?

Comment: Also, it seems like our netlify subdomain does not have this issue, but only the primary domain. I don't know enough about how everything works to have a conclusive answer, but that seems like it might be something on their end?

Comment: Maybe the less link,  its self closed,  As I see the others  are not self closed.

Comment: Good catch! I removed self closing tag, but unfortunately didn't fix the issue.

Comment: If this is a public source repo, can you link the code and/or your netlify site? I recognize the error, but want to confirm it is the same issue.

Comment: @talves Can't post the repo, but you can see the site at getkirs.com

Comment: Artur Käpp is correct. You have an issue with your `index.html` being cached and since the site is returning a `file not found` page, you get the error until your site is refreshed and gets the un-cached page. It would be hard for us to give a solution without knowing how your build and deploy is setup.

Comment: @talves what information would be helpful for you? I currently have my repo set up to have netlify publish a new update whenever a commit is made. I have added my netlify.toml file, where you can see the build commands and redirects. Let me know if you need any more information!

Comment: @Connor did you managed to solve the issue? We are having exactly the same problem

Comment: @wittolfr When I talked to netlify they said it was an issue with the service worker. Because we aren't using a service worker, I was able to just remove it and that seemed to fix our issues. The fix wasn't immediate though, due to browser caching, from what I can tell.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is cache + some non-existing script file.

1) If a local script file is missing it will probably handle it as a regular React application request and will return something starting with `<!DOCTYPE html>`, why you get the SyntaxError as it tries to parse the response as JS.

2) Additionally I think it has something to do with caching some parts of the application. Probably on your deploy you remove the old files, but the application is still looking for the old files with some previous hash: main.XXXXX.js. But during the deploy you removed those files completely and uploaded new scripts: main.YYYYYY.js.

Check the developer tools that all scripts return the expected JS file response and in case any of them are missing make appropriate changes to your cache headers and/or deployment scripts.

Comment: It looks like a caching error! Thank you for guiding me in the right direction.

Comment: For the edited part of the question I think you have multiple options available and first need to figure out what you want to achieve. Do you need service workers and what to cache and what not to. You might have better luck figuring these things out by reading the [CRA Deployment guide](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment) or searching their [Github issue tracker](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Uncaught+SyntaxError%3A+Unexpected+token+%3C) for similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML file is not completely valid which may be causing this issue.

- Script tags should be inside the head or body tag, not in between.
- Place your link tags inside the head tag.
- Remove the / from the end of your link tag.

There are a couple more issues with the posted code and improper async/defer usage.  You can see these by running your page through a validator like https://validator.w3.org

Comment: Cool tool! I fixed the errors and warnings. Also updated my original post to include the new index.html file. Unfortunately it did not fix the issue though.

Comment: Too bad!  That means the problem is probably in your javascript/css though.

Answer (score 0):

For me a simple `npm cache clean --force` worked as a charm.