# Errors after deploying my flutter web app using Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, flutter, web, firebase-hosting, flutter-web

I've tried to deploy my web app but when I go the the public adress, I have some errors that i can't fix. (I'm testing on Firefox). I've asked my developper friends but they have no idea how to solve it.

my errors:

> The script was loaded when its MIME type ("text / html") is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'    main.dart.js:1

my index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>MyAwesomeWebApp</title>

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json"/>

  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.4.456/pdf.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript">
    pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.4.456/pdf.worker.min.js";
    </script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>

    <script>
    var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "azaz",
      authDomain: "azaz",
      databaseURL: "azaz",
      projectId: "azaz",
      storageBucket: "azaz",
      messagingSenderId: "azaz",
      appId: "azaz",
      measurementId: "azaz"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    </script>

    <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js?v=906927181');
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks ! :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React firebase error after build and deploy SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50659063/react-firebase-error-after-build-and-deploy-syntaxerror-expected-expression-go)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you deploy using `firebase deploy` or `firebase deploy --only hosting` ?
I had the same issue using the first one. With the second one, no more issue.
You can learn more about this on the firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/test-preview-deploy

Hope it'll be helpful !